# Is it possible to trigger ExtendScript (with params) from a local web page?

Tags: javascript, localhost, extendscript

I have a script written in ExtendScript that generates artwork in Illustrator (CS3+). 
I also will have a local web page that will manage a small-scale database (utilizing localStorage or WebSQL).
Is there a way to trigger the ExtendScript from a web page, through a link or a button, passing it some parameters?

The page can be run from localhost apache if that's a requirement.
I could also migrate to Ai CS6 w/appropriate ExtendScript if that's a requirement.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3846626/1177119

Comment: I'm on Illustrator on Windows. I tried to write a vb helper script to take care of the arguments but it did not work. Also, while browsing the model viewer I didn't seem to find any methods that would allow Ai to run a script from file.

Comment: The link above will get the program to run your script.  As for parameters I have always written them to a text file (usually xml formatted) and have the script look for that rather than pass the parameters directly.  I have also run things in reverse quite succesfully - the InDesign user in my case runs a script and provides an ID number.  InDesign then queries the database via a webservice to determine what the appropriate parameters are to generate the document for that ID number.

Comment: What's the local web page written in? I would think you should call ExtendScript over COM (e.g. VBScript or also JScript) if you are using ASP server side scripting for the web page, or if you convert the web page to a Microsoft HTA application. That way you can directly manipulate ExtendScript API over COM from your web page triggered by UI actions from the user. This is based on top of the SO link Josh provided.