# How to execute an InDesign extendscript from command line?

Tags: command-line, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I need to execute a .jsx script for InDesign from command line (Windows).

For Illustrator, it works easily with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Support Files\Contents\Windows\Illustrator.exe" "...\myscript.jsx"
```

Both applications Illustrator and ExtendScript Toolkit CS6 open then the script is automatically launched.

When I try the same for InDesign, it doesn't work (InDesign says 'Unable to open myscript.jsx ...').

I also tried to launch ExtendScript Toolkit from command line as below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Utilities - CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe" "...\myscript.jsx"
```

The result is ExtendScript Toolkit application is opened with the script loaded, but nothing is executed.

Does anyone know how to launch the script? Is there a `-run` or `-cmd` argument to add?

Comment: This question might have some answers for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846626/is-it-possible-to-execute-jsx-scripts-from-outside-extendscript

Comment: I have no ready to use solution, but if you know a port of your started InDesign server you can start script like this: 

`\Adobe InDesign CC Server 2018\sampleclient" -host localhost:12345 ./your-script.jsx`

the InDesign server's port could be achieved by a combination of windows commands taskslist, netstat, find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution of yours could be to call a visualbasic script from command line. That VB would then call the indesign jsx file based on having referenced teh indesign application itself. Kind of tricky but should definitively work.

Comment: OK sounds great, thanks for the advice. Before I try, do you know if this method could solve the #include problem described above?

Comment: It should. Give a try with basic script with include.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how to do it.. do you have an example of how to call indesign with a jsx script?

Comment: I don't have Windows at hand to actually test it but I would start by looking at those links:

Comment: which links please?

Comment: Don't you see them in my last answer ?

Comment: No, it's written "... those links:" then nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112937/discussion-between-loic-and-superrache).

Answer (score 7):

For me on Osx it works like this:

```
/Applications/Adobe\ ExtendScript\ Toolkit\ CC/ExtendScript\ Toolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/ExtendScript\ Toolkit -run test.jsx
```

On Windows it should be:

```
"\path\to\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe" -run test.jsx
```

content of test.jsx:

```
//@target indesign
alert(app.name);
```

It needs the `-run` flag. When using `-cmd` it still executes the script but from ESTK. The `//@target indesign` gets ignored. With the `-run` the script gets passed to InDesign. Unfortunately the ESTK brings up a dialogue that warns to execute scripts from untrusted sources.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I just tried the -run with a simple script targetting InDesign and showing the name of the app, it works. Unfortunately, doesn't work when I include some files from the script. InDesign is launched but no error appear. To avoid the untrusted sources warning, I put every scripts and library in My Documents\Adobe Scripts folder.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes of course. So, I created a script test.jsx (http://pastebin.com/aLFRpr9k) including a library include.jsx (http://pastebin.com/M7ZimmP4). Both files are in the Adobe Scripts folder. When executing from ExtendScript window, I get well the alert, but not when I run the following command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Utilities - CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe" -run "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Adobe Scripts\test.jsx"

Comment: Hm. I have the same problem. Without the `#include` statement everything works fine. With it the script wont execute. Sorry. Looks like a problem with the ESTK. I'm currently working on a command line tool that bundles ExtendScripts that use the `#include`or `//@include`. Maybe it is useful for you. https://github.com/fabiantheblind/extendscript-bundlr I will publish it to npm soon.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the solution to bundle every include files. I will follow your project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to execute using node, these are the best two ways I have found to execute Indesign scripts.

- Version Agnostic

Credit [rendertom](https://github.com/rendertom) inside his [vscode/atom](https://github.com/rendertom/VSCode-Adobe-Script-Runner) plugins.

```
const outputFilePath =  path.resolve(os.homedir(), 'Documents', 'Adobe Scripts', 'myscript.js');
const hostCommand = {
        darwin: {
            command: 'osascript',
            args: [
                '-e',
                `tell application id "com.adobe.indesign" to do script "${outputFilePath}" language javascript`
            ],
            options: {}
        },
        win32: {
            command: 'powershell',
            args: [
                '-command',
                `"$app = new-object -comobject InDesign.Application; $app.DoScript('${outputFilePath}', 1246973031)"`
            ],
            options: {shell: true} // Windows requires a shell
        }
    };

    if (typeof hostCommand[process.platform] == 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('This platform is not supported');
    }

    const {command, args, options} = hostCommand[process.platform];
    const p = spawn(command, args, options);
```

Comment: I am getting Error: Cannot find module 'spawn' and if I try to install this through npm, it shows npm ERR! 404 Not Found: webworker@https://github.com/mirkok/node-webworker/tarball/master. any thoughts?

Comment: spawn is a module of child_process in node. `const { spawn } = require('child_process');` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I tried your solution, it open up indesign but it never run the script, the same script execute fine from script panel

Comment: sorry its working. Thank you. I am not able to pass dynamic arguments though.

Comment: @SameerJain What kind of arguments are you trying to pass? Are you trying to pass them to spawn?

Comment: for example `var argsArray = new Array("Hello", "another hello");` and then in hostCommand args `"$app = new-object -comobject InDesign.Application;$app.doScript('${outputFilePath}', 1246973031, ${argsArray})"`

Comment: Its working now, `"$app = new-object -comobject InDesign.Application;$params=@('param1','param2');$app.DoScript('${outputFilePath}', 1246973031, $params)"` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows at hand to actually test it but I would start by looking at those links:
Run VBS in command line : http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html

Run InDesign in VB:https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjj9_3JoPXMAhVI1BoKHUKMBT8QFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2FAdobe%2Fen%2Fdevnet%2Findesign%2Fsdk%2Fcs6%2Fscripting%2FInDesign_ScriptingGuide_VB.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFP8M8i3xrOqLp0zw3BGcNpnyhEXQ&sig2=pfFYnsgxXDpCf1A573JTDQ&bvm=bv.122676328,d.d2s

Look at the DoScript method for calling a JSX script.
myInDesign.DoScript myJavaScript,

Answer (score 0):

Without ExtendScript Toolkit and on a Mac, you can use AppleScript or JavaScript for Automation (JXA).

This is how it's done in the [jasminejsx](https://github.com/theasci/jasminejsx) library to execute jasmine specs in ExtendScript.

```sh
osascript -l "JavaScript" -e "var app = new Application('com.adobe.indesign'); app.doScript('$EXTENDSCRIPT', {language: 'javascript'});" &
```

[See code here.](https://github.com/theasci/jasminejsx/blob/ff5f6e5/run.sh#L11)